# TemplateDoesNotExist at /users/login/ registration/login.html

Tags: django

I got the following error while doing an exercise from Python Crash Course Book.

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Npg6j.png)

Code in files:

login.html:

```
 <p>
    <a href="{% url 'blogs:index' %}">Blogging Site</a> -
    {% if user.is_autenticated %}
      Hello, {{ user.username }}
    {% else %}
      <a href="{% url 'users:login' %}">Log in</a>
    {% endif %}
</p>

{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
```

urls.py of users app:

```
from django.urls import path, include

app_name = 'users'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLv0c.png)

Comment: where is login.html located? show us the folder structure of your project where this file can be seen.

Comment: I have added the folder structure image now. Please have a look.

Comment: why do I see "templates \ registration" instead of a folder "registration" under "templates"? the structure should be "users" -> "templates" -> "registration" -> "login.html".

Comment: Yes, 'registration' is a folder in 'templates'. VS code shows it this way.

Comment: @dirkgroten The structure is exactly like you said "users" -> "templates" -> "registration" -> "login.html". But, VSCode shows it has "templates/registration".

Comment: Is “users” in your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py?

Comment: I forgot doing that. Thanks a lot for your time.